# What's the difference between JHtml:script() and $doc->addScript?

Tags: php, development, module

I developed a module recently that required certain JS and CSS files to be injected into the `<head>` of each page. Initially, I used:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JURI::base(true).'/modules/mod_x/js/mod_x.js');
```

However, I noticed that when caching was enabled the site loaded both a cached version from `/cache` and non-cached version from `/modules/mod_x/js/`, causing JS errors.

When I changed this to:

```
JHtml::script(Juri::base().'modules/mod_x/js/mod_x.js');
```

The script was loaded only once, from cache, resolving these errors.

I [read in the docs](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aAdding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page) that the `addScript` method was more 'low level' than the `JHtml:script` method, but beyond saying that...

> Of course, you will also need to manually code some of the steps [that JHtml:script does for you] that would be done automatically using the [JHtml:script method] above [if you use addScript].

...no further detail is given.

So what's the difference? I assume `JHtml:script` eventually calls `addScript` on a document object at some point, but are other intermediary steps taken first?

Comment: I've rewritten the joomla docs a bit to try and update it - see if it makes more sense now?

Comment: @GeorgeWilson The Joomla docs have really improved recently. Thanks :)

Comment: Related question about stylesheets: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/10062/5239

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JHtml::script` has additional logic included. See http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtml.html#method_script for the API reference

By default it will detect debug setting and browser used and load the matching script. For example when debug is enabled it will load an uncompressed version of the file if present.

There are optional settings which allow to override the file on a template level and other things.

Michael Babker wrote a good guide how to use `JHtml::script()` to allow overrides:
http://www.babdev.com/blog/139-use-the-media-folder-allow-overridable-media

Function in repo for reference:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/html/html.php#L659

Official doc page which is now updated by George: [http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3%3aAdding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page)

Comment: thanks for the answer. The API reference is fairly terse - is there a more comprehensive explanation of the effects of detect_browser and detect_debug, and when you say 'optional settings' and 'other things' are these documented anywhere?

Comment: I've added a link to an article by Michael which explains the override part.
As for the debug and browser part, I don't think there is a documentation. You would have to read the code for that.

Comment: So if there is a uncompressed and compressed js file for example and debug is on then it will load filename-uncompressed.js and just filename.js when debug is off. For the browser when debug off it looks for filename-browser.js then filename-browser-browserversion.js etc.

Comment: In the interest of quality answers for our public beta, I will accept this once the answer has been updated to address my initial comments and subsequent clarification from @GeorgeWilson

Comment: Added link to doc page which now contains the information.

Comment: This is a cracking answer - thanks @Bakual and @GeorgeWilson!

Comment: Don't forget that that JHtml also can append the MD5sum of a script or stylesheet to cache-bust.

Comment: So now JHTML is deprecated?  How do we now account for overrides when using `addScript`?

Answer (score 4):

in two words:

- `JHtml::script()` - allow you to override the specific script (except that already attached to JDocument), depend from some factors (see @Bakual answer);
- `$doc->addScript()` - attach script directly to the document, without checking an overrides;

If you are the extension developer, then highly recommended use `JHtml::script()` when you add the script. This will allow for your users override some specific scripts, depend from what they want.
Also there similar method for css.