# Jhtml::script order - how to postpone until jQuery has been loaded?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

I use `JHtml::script` to add scripts to my pages in a custom-developed module. However, these scripts are injected into the head before J3 adds in jQuery - for example:

```
<!-- my module js -->
<script src="/modules/mod_tiles/js/jquery.isotope.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/modules/mod_tiles/js/jquery.hoverintent.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/modules/mod_tiles/js/mod_tiles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- then joomla loads jQuery --->
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I force Joomla to load jQuery before any other scripts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should call

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

before your other JHtml::script. AFAIK this makes sure that jQuery is loaded first.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me - placed in `mod_tiles.php` this forced jQuery to load first. Thank you!

Comment: @codinghands https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript#Important_notes_for_3rd_party_developers

Answer (score 2):

if I read your question correctly, you are developing your own module.

Try this, in default.php - the view of the module (in "tmpl" ):

`JHtml::stylesheet('modules/'.$module->module.'/assets/css/yourfile.css');`

`JHtml::script('modules/'.$module->module.'/assets/js/yourscript.js');`

Or this :

`JHtml::_('stylesheet', 'modules/'.$module->module.'/assets/css/anotherfile.css');`

`JHtml::_('script', 'modules/'.$module->module.'/assets/js/othercript.js');`

In both case, your JS file(s) should be injected after jQuery, providing that you created an "asset" folder, and a "css" and a "js" folder inside.

The second solution is more in accordance with joomla 3.X.X API.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The only change I made here was to add the `assets` folder - this made no different, and the scripts still load before jQuery does. I also wonder about the wisdom in putting this kind of code in a template file (particularly if there are multiple templates using the same scripts, DRY etc etc.)

Comment: Hem, your comment is weird -> "putting this kind of code in a template file ". I was, and maybe it was not clear enough, talking about a module developed by you and based on isotope.js and other JS scripts. I am very sorry if I was wrong and you are actually using a third party module called mod_tiles. BTW, there are other ways to insert JS scripts in a template.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound so harsh haha! Must of been up too early... You are exactly right, that is what I'm doing - it's my module. What I meant by template file was `default.php` in the `tmpl` (template) folder of the module.  I would of thought scripts should be loaded in `mod_tiles.php` (the 'controller') rather than `default.php` (the view).

Comment: Placing it in a tmpl/default.php allows overrides. In mod_tiles.php it can't be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem last week and it was related to where I was calling JHtml::script. Are you doing this in your view or the view's template? If you try to add the scripts in the view itself (views/yourview/view.html.php) they will be inserted before Joomla!'s own scripts, but if you add the scripts in the template (views/yourview/tmpl/default.php) they will be inserted after Joomla!'s scripts.

Good luck!

Comment: This a module with only mod_tiles.php, a helper.php file and a single template (default.php) in `tmpl`. I tried adding the scripts in both mod_tiles.php and default.php - both load before jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the method that the developer of `mod_tiles` has used to import the scripts. I assume they haven't stuck to Joomla coding standards in this situation.

You have 2 options (that I can think of) hwre:

1. If the scripts are being imported from a file within the **tmpl** folder within the module, you can perform a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) and change the way the script are being imported, using `JHtml`.
2. You can download and install [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327) which is a plugin that imports jQuery and places it above all other scripts.

Hope this helps

Comment: I developed the module - what method should I use? I asked this in a question (http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/325/whats-the-difference-between-jhtmlscript-and-doc-addscript) and was told JHtml::script was the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add my two-bits after the fact.  I've got a couple of scripts and style sheets that need to be loaded for every view that we have in the component, and wanted a single point to have that happen insuring also that they're loaded in the correct sequence.

In the file `components\myComponent\mycomponent.php`:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Include dependancies
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

JHtml::stylesheet('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), true);
JHtml::stylesheet('components/com_mycomponent/assets/css/mycomponent.css');

JHtml::_('jquery.framework');   // Make sure jQuery is loaded before component JS
JHtml::script( 'components/mycomponent/assets/js/jquery.cookie.js');

// Execute the task.
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Mycomponent');
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old topic but did you ever get to the bottom of this?
I've just experienced the same problem.  I have identified the CAUSE but not the problem/solution; I have a sneaky suspision that it is a BUG but could do with someone else trying it out.

Scenario: You have created a module that includes a jQuery dependant script so you use the following in your default.php view:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript("media/mod_accordion/js/accordion.js");
```

You then install the module and give it a module position, lets say 'left'.
When you look at the front end source code everything looks good, all the scripts load after the scripts that are included in

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
```

HOWEVER 
if you give the module a position 'accordion' and use the joomla loadposition feature to add the module to an article

```
{loadposition accordion}
```

then accordion.js gets added BEFORE the bootstrap.framework files.

The only way I have been able to bodge it to work is to add the script as an inline script rather than being included in the head.

EDIT:  same goes for including the css; it is being added to the top of the list of css declaration (before the template and bootstrap css files).  The bodge for this is to add !important to the css declarations.