# What does JHtml::_ do?

Tags: jhtml

I've seen code like this:

```
JHtml::_("script", "path/to/script.js");
JHtml::_("stylesheet", "path/to/stylesheet.css");
JHtml::_("jquery.framework");
```

What does the underscore function do here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the time

```
JHtml::_("script", "path/to/script.js");
JHtml::_("stylesheet", "path/to/stylesheet.css");
JHtml::_("jquery.framework");
```

will call

```
JHtml::Script("path/to/script.js");
JHtml::Stylesheet("path/to/stylesheet.css");
JHtmlJquery::framework();
```

However there is a small difference between the two calls. The first one allows system plugins to override the core classes.

#### Example

Let's assume you don't like the JQuery version shipped with Joomla for some funny reason. You could now create a system plugin and in the `onAfterInitialise` event you just register a different method for the `jquery.framework` call. You can do that using [`JHtml::register('jquery.framework', 'ClassToLoad::MethodToCall')`](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtml.html#method_register)

Michael Babker has written an [example plugin](https://github.com/mbabker/bs3-demo/) which would allow to change the loaded Bootstrap version. That may help to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a shortcut, to save typing I suppose. [The documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtml.html#method__) calls it a class loader method.

```
JHtml::_("script", "path/to/script.js");
# is the same as:
JHtml::script("path/to/script.js");

JHtml::_("stylesheet", "path/to/stylesheet.css");
# is the same as:
JHtml::stylesheet("path/to/stylesheet.css");

JHtml::_("jquery.framework");
# is the same as:
require_once 'libraries/cms/html/jquery.php';
JHtmlJquery::framework();
```

There's an algorithm that transforms the first argument to the correct function name, you can have a look [a the source code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/78e257253a97b1b862aa0b56fa768b26f12fcea2/libraries/cms/html/html.php#L92) in the file `libraries/cms/html/html.php`.

Comment: JHtml::_('script') is not exactly the same as JHtml::script(). The first one allows system plugin to override the core methods. Michael Babker did some example plugin here: https://github.com/mbabker/bs3-demo/blob/master/plg_system_bootstrap3/bootstrap3.php

Comment: @Bakual - definitely write this as an answer. I've been waiting a long time to know this

Comment: Done. hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

**Same like this**

```
    JHtml::_("script", "path/to/script.js");
    JHTML::script('sample.js', 'templates/custom/js/');

    JHtml::_("stylesheet", "path/to/stylesheet.css");
    JHtml::stylesheet('com_search/search.css', array(), true);

    JHtml::_("jquery.framework");
    JHtml::jquery('jquery.ui');
    JHtml::jquery('jquery.ui', array('sortable'));
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Which lines are the same as the others?

Comment: You can write in two ways for example JHtml::_("script", "path/to/script.js"); (here _ are there) or JHTML::script('sample.js', 'templates/custom/js/'); (here _ is replace to script) both are provide same answer

Comment: Your edit made it a bit clearer, but I'm still confused as to why loading `script.js` is the same as loading `sample.js`.

Comment: I suspect he meant to write JHtml::_("script", "templates/custom/js/sample.js"); -- the 'path/to' stuff is just boilerplate to be replaced by the actual path to the script file. The underscore method takes the first argument as the identifier for what it should load.